# Discard all changes in Xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

I have an Xcode 4.2 project that uses git as repository. I make some changes in my source code files. 
In order to discard changes in one file, I do the following:

- Select that file in the **Source Tree**
- Go to *File > Source Control > Discard Changes* to discard changes I made in that file

But I want to discard all changes in all files in my project. How to do it?

Answer (score 4):

**File > Source Control > Commit** (⌥⌘C), on the left pane select the files you want to reset, right click on selection and click **Discard Changes** in the context menu.

Answer (score 2):

From the command line in the git repository you could do

```
git co -- .
```

to reset the files to the HEAD revision.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to go to the commit screen to discard changes.  Just highlight the file in the Project Navigator and select **File > Source Control > Discard Changes**.

Comment: This is a great approach. I almost discarded all of my changes to get rid of a corrupted storyboard file. You just saved so much work :) Thanks.